# How to scale the app locally using cluster package in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I want to scale my application using cluster package of meteor . I have used these two commands in the terminal.

```
CLUSTER_DISCOVERY_URL=mongodb://mongo-url CLUSTER_SERVICE=web    
CLUSTER_ENDPOINT_URL=http://ipaddresss:port meteor
```

The `CLUSTER_DISCOVERY_URL` is the `URL` to a `MongoDB` database. The cluster package uses the MongoDB database to communicate between the Meteor applications. This database can be the Meteor application database (where all your other collections are stored) or a different one.

The `CLUSTER_SERVICE` variables stores a name for your application which is used internally by the package.

The `CLUSTER_ENDPOINT_URL` is the `URL` to your application.

**After running these commands my application has not started on my local machine and it does not show any error in the console.**

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: https://github.com/meteorhacks/cluster

is it this package? if so, this package has been dead for 2 years now

Comment: yes , this is a package.

Comment: Try this list:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/alternatives-to-meteorhacks-cluster/42904

Comment: Have you tried this package ?